# How to freeze angular component?

Tags: angular

I would like freeze the angular component. All view listeners of the component.

For example: {{datas.title}}

If title has changed so the view must stay the same and ignore changements during the freeze.

How to freeze a component ?

Thanks :)

Comment: by **freeze** what you mean>?

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the component from automatic change detection by calling `detach()` on [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    {{datas.title}}
  `
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {    
  }

  freeze() {
    this.changeDetector.detach();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `{{datas.title}}`
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {    
  }

  freeze() {
    this.changeDetector.detach();
  }
  melt() {
    this.changeDetector.reattach();
  }
}
```

Official docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef